# MySQL: daily average value

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I have a table with a 'timestamp' column and a 'value' column where the values are roughly 3 seconds apart.

I'm trying to return a table that has daily average values.

So, something like this is what i'm looking for.

```
| timestamp  | average |
| 2010-06-02 |  456.6  |
| 2010-06-03 |  589.4  |
| 2010-06-04 |  268.5  |
etc...
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT DATE(timestamp), AVG(value)
FROM table
GROUP BY DATE(timestamp)
```

Since you want the day instead of each timestamp

Answer (score 2):

```
 select DATE(timestamp), AVG(value)
 from TABLE
 group by DATE(timestamp)
```

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that your timestamp column only contains information about the day, but not the time. That way, the dates can be grouped together:

```
select timestamp, AVG(value) as average
from TABLE_NAME
group by timestamp
```

Comment: I don't think he actually has discrete values with such large deltas in the timestamp field. I am guessing he also needs processing of the field, to ignore the hour.

Comment: Yea, you are probably right. I will leave the answer up since your info might be useful to someone.